# Import numpy from macOS Terminal running python launches but not from python script

Tags: python, macos, numpy, terminal

My goal is to be able to run NumPy through simple scripts. Being new at this, simple is not so simple. From the Terminal running python, NumPy works just fine. However, I can not import it from a script. The numpy sample runs from python with the following result.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

However, from my script, runNumPy.py

```
#!/usr/bin/sh/env python3.6
print("Hello world! from runNumPy.py in python called by Terminal")
import sys, os
print("Current Working Directory: ", os.getcwd())
import numpy as np
```

I get

```
>>> a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

I have tried it with "import numpy as np" and without "as np."

My Terminal script is

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo "Hello, world! Starts helloWorld.sh Terminal script."
source opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate bioETE
cd opt; cd anaconda3; cd envs; cd bioETE; cd lib; cd python3.6; cd site-packages
python ./runNumPyS.py  #This runs runNumPyS.py from the terminal
python ./runNumPy.py    #This runs the runNumPy.py from the terminal
python
```

It's output is

```
Hello, world! Starts helloWorld.sh Terminal script.
Hello world: from helloWorld.py in python script called by Terminal
Hello world! from runNumPy.py in python called by Terminal
Current Working Directory:  home/opt/anaconda3/envs/bioETE/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Python 3.6.12 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep  8 2020, 17:50:39) 
[GCC Clang 10.0.0 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

As stated before my goal is to begin NumPy at the python prompt >>> without using another import statement. This shell script works fine. It calls the python scripts.

In the output above, the first "Hello World" was to show the shell script was working before I went any further. The other two, "Hello World", were to see if the python scripts were called.

You can see by th python script output the python print commands and sys and os import calls worked OK. The system call seems to tell me I am in the correct directory..??

The runNumPy.py script is

```
#!/usr/bin/sh/env python3.6
print("Hello world! from runNumPy.py in python called by Terminal")
import sys, os
print("Current Working Directory: ", os.getcwd())
import numpy as np
```

At the python prompt, I get the following error.

```
>>> a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Clearly, numpy has not been imported. Again, at this same prompt, if I type in the "import numpy as np" first, NumPy works just fine.

NumPy's module numpy is located at

```
home/opt/anaconda3/envs/bioETE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy
```

I've tried placing python script, runNumPy.py, in two places.

```
1)home/opt/anaconda3/envs/bioETE/lib/python3.6/site-packages
2)home/opt/anaconda3/envs/bioETE/lib/python3.6/
```

Neither place seems to work. I'm stuck for the moment. Any and all helpful suggestions or a solution or two will be appreciated.

Comment: You're running runNumPy.py with MacOS Python, but you don't have NumPy installed for that version. Remove the #!/usr/bin/sh/env python3.6 in the first line, do `conda activate bioETE`, then `conda install numpy`, and then run your script using `python runNumPy.py`. Also, putting runNumPy.py in site-packages doesn't sound like a good idea...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I followed your recommendation and my issue  still persists. However, I do have an updated conda with the comment: # All requested packages already installed. So of course I removed the install conda from it.

Comment: Usually the simplest way to check which Python you are using is to write in the terminal `which python` (works for any command). You should be getting `/home/opt/anaconda3/envs/bioETE/bin/python/`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was just confirming the correct one was responding to the scripts from the conda environment. I guess my short question is: can a python script return  variables, functions, and classes to the python CLI "remembering" them to be use interactively without having to re-enter them. In my case, except for the print command, what happens in the script stays in the script.

Comment: Not that I know of. But, have you taken a look at ipython? You can run a script using `%run myscript.py`, and the variables will be in the scope. You can install ipython using conda as well.

Comment: Thanks, I might look in to iPython. As of now I believe my issue has been resolved. Note the advice from vy32 below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write:

> As stated before my goal is to begin NumPy at the python prompt >>> without using another import statement. This shell script works fine. It calls the python scripts.

This is actually not a good goal. You should try to get out of the habit of running python from the interactive prompt. It's hard to develop significant programs that way. If you really want to run Python this way, you should look into use Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab, both of which are included in your Python anaconda release.

The reason you don't want to just hack a bunch of stuff into your environment is that you won't be able to create scripts or programs that others can easily use. This is also the reason that you don't want to build a dependency on your current directory into your program. You should rely on `site-packages` being in `sys.path`; you should not be changing your current directory so that `site-packages` is your current directory.

Does this make sense?

However, if you really want to muck with the command line environment, you will find it useful to read this document:

- https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

In particular, set the environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` to contain the python commands that you want executed before python starts up in interactive mode.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, and yes, what you are telling me makes a lot of sense. After I got started on this little project, momentum kept me going. I thought the code would work, surly there's a way even if it is awkward.

Comment: Excellent! I just added % export PYTHONSTARTUP="./runNumPyS.py"  to my terminal script and "voila" numpy as np already running on python startup. Magic! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. BTY the script runNumPyS.py only has "import numpy as np" written in it which comes after the "export" in the terminal script.

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember to read the documentation. It is your friend.